# Why does my program end in an endless loop?

Tags: loops, while-loop, fortran

I can't understand why it's happening but it becomes an endless loop when I start the program. What do I do wrong ?

```
 program Hello
  REAL K1,K2,RP,G,m,t,time,R1,R2
  G = 6.67384 * (10**(-11))   
  m = 5.9723E24       
  t = 0.1               
  RP = 6371000               
  K1 = 15                    
  K2 = 10                         
  R1 = K1 + RP
  R2 = K2 + RP
  r = R1
  DO WHILE (r > R2)
    r = r - ((Gm*t/r**2)*t)
    time = time + t
  END DO
 write (*,*) "Time = seconds" 
 write (*,*) (Gm*t/r**2) 
 end program Hello
```

Comment: Please use `implicit none` as the second line and fix the compilation problems that follow.

Comment: I used implicit none and fixed Gm thing but its still the same uses %35 cpu and doesnt finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gm` is not declared and is implicitly to be `real`. The value of `Gm` is not set, but it is very likely 0. Therefore `r` is the same all the time.

You probably wanted to type `G*m` but you have `Gm` in `((Gm*t/r**2)*t)`.

Always use `implicit none` in your programs. It is VERY important.

And as you found yourself `10**(-11)` is zero, because it is an integer expression. `E` or `D` must be used for exponent in floating point expressions.

Comment: write (*,*) ((G*m/r**2)*(t**2)    i did what you have said to me. im using this and still it says its equals to 0.

Comment: I solved it i used E-11 instead of 10**(-11) and its solved thanks for helping :)

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved your problem.